# Dagger 2, can not inject presenter in my activity

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, mvp, dagger-2

I am new in Dagger2.
I have a problem with inject presenter in my activity
I try to resolve my problem after read this article https://android.jlelse.eu/inject-interfaces-without-providing-in-dagger-2-618cce9b1e29 but it was not helpe me. I hope someone help me, I spend all day tring to resolve it...

here is my modules:

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val appContext: Context) {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    internal fun provideContext(): Context {
        return appContext
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    internal fun providePreferences(): SharedPreferences {
        return appContext.getSharedPreferences(
                appContext.resources.getString(R.string.shared_preferences_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideMakeCheckPresenter (p : 
    MakeCheckPresenter<MakeCheckMvpView>)
        : MakeCheckMvpPresenter<MakeCheckMvpView>
}
```

here is my component:

```
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, ActivityModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MakeCheckActivity makeCheckActivity);
}
```

here is my App class:

```
class App : android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component = buildComponent()
    }

    protected fun buildComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build()
    }

    companion object {
        var component: AppComponent? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

here is my activity:

```
class MakeCheckActivity : BaseActivity(), MakeCheckMvpView {
    @Inject lateinit var presenter: MakeCheckMvpPresenter<MakeCheckMvpView>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.new_check_activity)
        App.getComponent().inject(this)
    }
}
```

here is my presenter:

```
class MakeCheckPresenter<V : MakeCheckMvpView>
@Inject constructor() : BasePresenter<MakeCheckMvpView>(), MakeCheckMvpPresenter<MakeCheckMvpView> {
    override fun saveEnterpriseId(enterpriseId: Int) {
        //model.enterpriseId
    }
}
```

here is interfaces for presenter and view:

```
interface MakeCheckMvpView : MvpView {
}
interface MakeCheckMvpPresenter<in V : MakeCheckMvpView> : MvpPresenter<V> {
    fun saveEnterpriseId(enterpriseId : Int)
}
```

and here base classes:

```
open class BasePresenter<V : MvpView> @Inject constructor(): MvpPresenter<V> {
}
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MvpView{
}
```

and always when i build i have this error:

```
...\di\component\AppComponent.java:62: error: ..ui.check_making.MakeCheckMvpPresenter<? super ...ui.check_making.MakeCheckMvpView> cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
e: 

e:     void inject(MakeCheckActivity makeCheckActivity);
```

how can I resolve it?

Comment: Does it work when you switch `@Binds` to `@Provides` on top of your presenter provider method in your ActivityModule.

Comment: no, it does not works too

Comment: You are binding `MakeCheckPresenter<MakeCheckMvpView>` but you are requesting injection for `MakeCheckMvpPresenter<? super MakeCheckMvpView>`. Please check your `in` and `out` generics

Comment: this my interface: interface MakeCheckMvpPresenter<in V : MakeCheckMvpView> : MvpPresenter<V> {
    fun saveEnterpriseId(enterpriseId : Int)
}

Comment: oh, thanks David, I removed "in" modifier from my presenter interface for MakeCheckMvpView and it is work!!! cool!